# How to change functionality of toString() code snippet in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Is there in Netbeans IDE possibility how to change its behaviour in "into toString()..." (Alt+Shift+S) code snippet function from context menu?

I would like to include into final generated toString() method selected methods (mostly getters) from class and its superclass.

Comment: Are you referring to the `toString()` code generator from the "Generate (Alt + Insert)" menu?

Comment: @jmrodrigg - yes, this code generator I mean (shortcut can be edited).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to "override" the default `toString()` behaviour of the *Generate (Alt + Insert)* menu, but you can create your own code generator for your custom `toString()` method.

You need to create a "Netbeans Module Project". Here you have a complete guide:

**Code Generator Integration** - http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-generator.html

Comment: Thanks, it looks like as an solution. Btw. is there some reason why Netbeans doesn't include selected methods / variables from particular class and/or superclass?

Comment: What do you mean for "selected methods/variables"? If you want to Insert getters/setters for your attributes you have the "Getters|Setters|Getters & setters" options in the "Generate Code" menu.

Comment: No, I don't mean create getters and setters. I mean to have in toString() generator an option to include these (but selected only) variables and methods into final generated toString() method. It makes me wonder why Netbeans doesn't allow this behaviour, is this some kind of security problem or antipattern?

Comment: I don't know, the "Insert code" is thought to create the code folds you need, then it is your turn to decide how to implement them. A `toString()` could be as simple as printing some methods and vars in a `System.out.println()` but it also can be formatted to more specific needings. Please vote positively the answer if you think convenient.

Comment: awww... it is for netbeans 8, and jmonkey ide is older one :(, but thx!