# How to modify toString() method in netbeans (java)

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to change the template of the `toString()` method when I generate it using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd> and I don't know how.

Look, when I generate the method using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd> the ide give that to me:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "name=" + name + " id=" + id;
}
```

And I want to change the auto generation to something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\n name=" + name + "\n id=" + id;
}
```

Comment: Change it how? You change the code once template has generated it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change functionality of toString() code snippet in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473326/how-to-change-functionality-of-tostring-code-snippet-in-netbeans)

Comment: @Andreas i edit my question so if you can take a look it would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: There is no easy way to customize the **`toString()`** method in NetBeans to do what you want.

Long answer:

[1](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-generator.html) As you point out, using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> will generate a **`toString()`** method like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "JavaApplication4{" + "name=" + name + ", id=" + id + '}';
}
```

That is close to what you want, but unfortunately NetBeans provides no way to customize that generated code apart from allowing you to specify which variables to include/exclude.

[2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-373?filter=allopenissues) You can also use <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to generate a different **`toString()`** method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

As noted in the comment of that generated code, you can customize it, but it doesn't really help you for two reasons:

- There is no way to specify the names of the variables in the template.
- Even if you could do that, the same template code would also by used by other generated methods such as **`hashCode()`** and **`equals()`**, which wouldn't be good.

[3] One other possible approach would be to generate the code using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>, and then use a regular expression to modify the generated code:

- Locate the line containing **`public String toString()`**
- On the following line insert **`\n`** immediately after each instance of   **`+ "`**. (i.e. space-plus-space-doublequote).

Depending on how frequently you will be creating **`toString()`** methods, that approach may be better than error-prone manual editing of every generated `toString()` method.

[4] A non-trivial approach would be to write your own [Code Generator](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-generator.html) to add an entry on the popup menu when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>. However, that seems like a lot of effort just to customize the output from **`toString()`**.

[5] Another approach would be to [raise a bug report with NetBeans for an improvement to the existing functionality](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-373?filter=allopenissues), by adding an option to include a line feed before each variable when generating the **`toString()`** method.
While that is the ideal solution, and would presumably be trivial to implement, it probably wouldn't be very high on their priority list.

Comment: Thanks a lot @skomisa appreciate your response i will check if I found a solution.